# Upload a file with Jmeter in a JSF web application

Tags: java, performance, testing, jsf, jmeter

I'm trying to upload a file in a web application, is made with JSF.
This is the request that is recorder with the blazemeter's extension

[blaze meter request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NpXM.png)

This is the request in the browser

[browser request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wmxq4.png)

And the value of the Webkitform is this:

[web kit form value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z9Bh.png)

I see the name of the file. But when I run the script it doesn't upload the file. The file is in the same folder where is the script.

After I run the script I check on the web and I see that other form fields that are sent with others request of the script are saved, but not the file.

What configuration must have the request? Or what else do I need to upload the file? Thank you.

UPDATE:

I recorded with JMeter proxy, but the problem when I execute de request is that de boundary is not correct, how can I generate the correct boundary?

[recorded with proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekbFG.png)
[recorded with proxy 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/163Us.png)

The request (the correct boundary must be like this ------WebKitFormBoundaryj2OVXs0ClWJHXrKH):

[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vP4w.png)

**UPDATE**

I solved first recording with JMeter proxy and using HttpClient 4 implementation in the request that upload the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your file has to be in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation. Try copying it there and re-running your script. If it still fails - check [*jmeter.log* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging) for any suspicious entries

I would recommend re-recording your file upload request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder).

1. Copy your file to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
2. Configure your browser to use JMeter as the proxy
3. Perform the upload request in your browser
4. Make sure that the file is present in JMeter's "bin" folder while replaying

See [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) article for more details.

---

Additionally I would recommend inspecting your request and response details using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener as it appears your `${jsfViewState2}` variable is not getting resolved so it might be the case you're not even getting logged in as [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) fails somewhere somehow.

Comment: I check the request and response details and the value for variable jsfViewState2 is ok. I also check the log and there is an error "2019-03-04 20:38:50,984 WARN o.a.j.u.Document: Error document parsing.
org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException: Failed to detect the character encoding of a document" and Error document parsing.

Comment: Also I see in the log  2019-03-04 21:12:43,079 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Stored:test.pdf

Comment: Hi Dmitri, I updated the original post, do you know what can I do to send the correct boundary? thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "correct" boundary? It may be [almost whatever you want](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html) and define in [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header. If you look at [Testing REST API File Uploads in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-advanced-rest-api-file-uploads-jmeter) article it defines a custom boundary `jmeter_is_great` and everything works like a charm

Comment: When I look the request the boundary has this format boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryj2OVXs0ClWJHXrKH

Comment: If I send the request like the proxy recorded then Jmeter generates a random boundary (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vP4w.png)  and if I send the request only using the body and the header like in this tutorial "Testing REST API File Uploads in JMeter" it doesn't upload the file either.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with random boundary, it must be equal for all message parts

Comment: Ok, I understand, but the file did not upload. the file is in the bin folder, I'm sending the request like the proxy recorded https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekbFG.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/163Us.png   What can I be missing? I really appreciate your help. I don't know what can be wrong.

Comment: I'm using the debugger and this is what I get https://ibb.co/3vVr23F and the raw response look like this https://ibb.co/9rv1BzG

Comment: Hi Dmitri, I solved using HttpClient 4 implementation. Thank you very much for your time and help.